# Removing Widgets is Pygame Widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame-widgets

I am having issues figuring out how to remove a widget in "Pygame Widgets." Because once you define a widget it is always on top of whatever else I might be displaying.

The only way I found to stop displaying widgets is to remove the `pygame_widgets.update(events)` function. But this this disable all widgets so I cannot just display some of them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use: --> your widget: `widget.hide()`, the widget is still there but, will not be drawn. I had the same problem, then i implemented some layers into WidgetHandler.